# Script that will produce cities in Canada using sakila database?

Tags: python

Using the Python programming language and the sakila database, create a Python program that will produce the following output:

```
City Name and Country Name
```

For all of the cities in the database that are in Canada.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a community where we answer programming questions for those who are learning how to program. This is not a code writing or homework service.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?
I am assuming that 'sakila' is a mysql database. Do you know the structure of the cities table?

Here's some starter code:

```py
import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","test123","TESTDB" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# check table name and isolate cities in canada
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tableOfCities WHERE country=='CANADA'")

rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```